# Calendar control to show databound date

Tags: asp.net, calendar, web-controls

I have a databound calendar control that loads the date from the database.
The problem I have is that it defaults to todays date when the form is loaded, although when you scroll to the loaded date you see that the correct date is in fact selected. How can I force it to show the loaded date from the database from the start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a work around. I set the Calendar control's SelectedDate property at design time, and then in the Prerender event of the control, I use the sender's SelectedDate property to set the VisibleDate property of the Control. It then shows both the correct month and correct selected date. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the Calendars `Visible` date?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visibledate.aspx

Gets or sets the DateTime value that specifies the month to display on the Calendar control. The default value is DateTime.MinValue, which displays the month that contains the date specified by TodaysDate.

You know, documentation is made for reading :)

Comment: When I set the Visible date, it loads and displays the date correctly. But now when I select a different date, it defaults to the first of the month in which I selected the date - and saves that back to the DB when I do an Update. This behaviour is the same for when both the Selected date and Visible date is binded and for when only the Visible date is binded.

Comment: without knowing any details of how your different event handlers are implemented that is all gibberish. You asked how to force the calendar to show a specified Date on initial load and that i've told you.

Comment: I appreciate your input Pauli :-)

Comment: when are you setting Visible and SelectedDate? are you making sure not to set them on PostBack?

Comment: Well I am setting the properties at design time by clicking on the calendar control's smart tag and then Edit DataBindings..

Comment: can't help you there... wysiwyg editors gives me nightmares! :)